# Fully dynamic k-shortest-path

Tags: algorithms, graphs, shortest-path, dag

I have a directed acyclic graph with positive edge weights. It is constantly changing in that nodes are deleted and added. For each change, I need to find the $k$ shortest paths.

My current approach is that I plan to run Eppstein's algorithm for each change, but I'd like to be able to reuse some of the calculations I've done in previous versions of the graph.

What is the fastest algorithm for this problem, considering it will run over multiple graph changes?